# Добавление тэгов (chip) в div

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Можно ли поместить выбираемые теги не в поле инпута, а в div снизу? https://codepen.io/Dgacarda/pen/OBxKQE?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-combobox :items="items" v-model="chips" label="Выберите тег" clearable chips solo multiple>
      <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
        <v-chip :selected="data.selected" close @input="remove(data.item)">
          <strong>{{ data.item }}</strong>&nbsp;
          <span>(interest)</span>
        </v-chip>
      </template>
    </v-combobox>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      chips: [],
      items: ['Streaming', 'Eating']
    }
  },

  methods: {
    remove (item) {
      this.chips.splice(this.chips.indexOf(item), 1)
      this.chips = [...this.chips]
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div id="output">{{chips}}</div>`

```
<div id="output2">
  <span v-for="(item, index) in chips" :key="index">{{item}}</span>
</div>
```

вы ведет выделенные
https://codepen.io/Rusic/pen/Xxzzqx?editors=1010 Если нужно оформить, то v-for поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!